# How to be safe when PHP6 is released and ereg regex is turned into an extension instead of core

Tags: php

For those of you who don't know what's gonna happen in PHP6, here's a nice short read: http://jero.net/articles/php6

Now, if you have functions that depend on ereg and you don't have control over the php.ini file on the server that's hosting your scripts, how do you deal with that?

For instance, this function here:

```
function currentDateTime() {
  list($micro, $Unixtime) = explode(" ",microtime());
  $sec= $micro + date("s", $Unixtime);
  $sec = mb_ereg_replace(sprintf('%d', $sec), "", ($micro + date("s", $Unixtime)));
  return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $Unixtime).$sec;
}
```

It seems to be dependant on ereg, so how do I replace this?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is going to be upgrading to PHP6? You don't have any option to stay on an older version?

Comment: Oh, I'm not on any server at all, I'm just speakig hypothetically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could re-write to use the [preg functions](http://www.php.net/preg_match).

Edit: [dynamically loading](http://www.php.net/dl) seems to be deprecated...

Comment: +1 for mentioning preg functions... which have been recommended over ereg functions for years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ini_set()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to set PHP configuration values within your script in the event that you don't have control over your `php.ini` file. But I recommend trying to migrate to `preg_` over `ereg_` at some point. PCRE is much more useful and powerful than POSIX regular expressions, and are largely compatible.